# Anyone know how to remove ꟼ from my MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql on my mac through Dbeaver. I have uploaded a csv which I recieved from a webscraping project in python.

ꟼꟼ Values in my string.

[image: ꟼꟼ Values in my string]

I have tried the trim function and also the substring_index function, neither working.

Comment: Those are paragraph (pilcrow) characters. They likely represent line breaks.

Comment: You can just copy one of those characters from the db and use the replace function to remove it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 1):

Good point Jesse, I didn't fully test the previous one, so something like this:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(column, char(10), ''), char(13), '')
```

Comment: MySQL does not have escape sequences like that. You have to use the `CHAR()` function. In this case, a line break would be `CHAR(10)`. Note that if they are Windows-style line breaks (`\r\n`), you will need to replace `\r` as well which is `CHAR(13)`.

Comment: Correction, `\N` (uppercase) does appear to be a valid escape sequence in MySQL, but it's not a line break. It's shorthand for `NULL` and was deprecated in MySQL 5.7.